# Datatable 1st column is always sortable

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

The first column of the angular datatable is showing the sortable icon, even when I have added the `DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()` in `dtColumnDefs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.withOption('order', [])** to remove the sorting arrows from first column.

Sample :

```
self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().
                withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                .withOption('order', []);
```